# how to get unpredictable directory path with python?

Tags: python, unix, path

first, I will describe in short the problem I want to solve:

I have a system UNIX based, that running an automatic run that causing images creation.

those images, are saving in a directory that creating during the run and the name of the directory is unpredictable [the name is depends in so many factors and not constant.]

that directory, is created under a constant path, which is:

/usr/local/insight/results/images/toolsDB/lauto_ptest_s + str(datetime.datetime.now()).split()[
0] + /w1

So, now I got a constant form of path which is a part of my full path.
I tried to get the full path in a stupid way:

I wrote a script that open a new terminal by pressing ctrl+alt+sft+w, writing in the terminal the cd command to the constant path, and pressing tab in order to complete the full path [In the constant path there is always one directory that created so pressing tab will always get me the full path].

Theoretically, I have a full path in a terminal, how can I copy this full path and make the function return it?

this is my code:

```
import pyautogui
import datetime


def open_images_directory():

    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'alt', 'shift', 'w')
    pyautogui.write(
        'cd' + ' /usr/local/insight/results/images/toolsDB/lauto_ptest_s' + str(datetime.datetime.now()).split()[
            0] + '/w1/')
    pyautogui.sleep(0.5)
    pyautogui.hotkey('tab') # now I have a full path in terminal which I want to return by func


open_images_directory()
```

Comment: Couldn't you use some `glob` for that?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm a noob, so I don't know what glob it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how you use `pyautogui` for that, but the proper solution would be search the directory structure with some [glob patterns](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)

Example:

```
from pathlib import Path

const_path = Path("const_path")
for path in [p for p in const_path.rglob("*")]:
    if path.is_dir():
        print(f"found directory {path}")
    else:
        print(f"found your image {path}")
```

`const_path.rglob("*")` searches every path recursively, (so it will contain every subdirectory), the last one will be your path you are searching for.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment.

Unfortunately, there is a little issue. 

This is the traceback: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "open_terminal.py", line 12, in <module>
    open_images_directory()
  File "open_terminal.py", line 9, in open_images_directory
    path = [p for p in const_path.rglob("*") if not p.is_dir()][0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: It means that you have no file under specific path at all! I updated the program so you can debug it by yourself